# iOS - RxRealm - Is it possible to get updated event even if dataset is not changed

Tags: ios, swift, realm, rx-swift

`iOS` - RxRealm - Is it possible to get updated event even if the dataset is not changed

Is it possible in RxRealm to get a notification even if my dataset is the same?
When I subscribe to the collection (no items at app launch) I get back an empty array. (it's fine at this point)
My problem is that my API request may return with an empty array as well, and in this case, I didn’t get any notification from the **RxRealm.collection**, So I don't know if my request is finished or I was just reading the database.

I tried to call `realm.refresh()` but it didn't help

This is what I'm observing:

```swift
func findAll() -> Results<T> {
    return realm.objects(T.self)
}
    .
    .
    .

Observable.collection(from: findAll()).map(Array.init)
```

This is how I rebuild my database after API request is finished:

```swift
func rebuildDatabase(objects: [T], with update: Bool = false) {
        realm.refresh() // trying to force refresh event
        do {
            realm.beginWrite()
            realm.delete(self.findAll())
            realm.add(objects, update: update)
            try realm.commitWrite()
        } catch {
            Log.error(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to archive this behavior with some configuration or is there any line of code that will force the notification? Thank for all the answers

Comment: Why would you want an event if the data hasn't changed? That feels like a code smell to me.

Comment: @DanielT. because I would like to know if my request is finished and returned an empty array or it's just the values from the realm database

Comment: If you want to know something about the request, then look at the result of the request. You don't want "spooky action at a distance" in your app.

Comment: it's not a "spooky action at a distance". I use a unidirectional dataflow architecture, where I'm observing the realm database and my request only writes to my database. @DanielT. so if I check directly my response, I'm violating the architecture